# Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with real entries such that $A$ is invertible. If $Det(A)=k$,and $Det(A+kadj(A))=0$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with real entries such that $A$ is invertible.

If $Det(A)=k$,and

$Det(A+kadj(A))=0$,

then find the value of $Det(A-kadj(A))$

My attempt:

$Det(A+kadj(A))=0$

$Det(A)Det(A+kadj(A))=0$

$Det(A^2+kAadj(A))=0$

$Det(A^2+k^2I)=0$

Using same steps,I get $Det(A-kadj(A))=\frac{1}{k}Det(A^2-k^2I)$

but can't understand what to do next

Answer (score 2):

Since you're given that $A$ is a $2\times 2$ you could brute force it...

Calculating the determinant of
$$
\begin{align*}
A^2 + k^2I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a + k^2 & b \\
c & d + k^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

and setting it equal to zero gives that $a+d = -(1+k^2)$. Now solving for the determinant of

$$
\begin{align*}
A^2 - k^2I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a - k^2 & b \\
c & d - k^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

gives $\frac 1k \det(A^2 -k^2I) = 2k(1 + k^2)$.

Comment: The answer given is $4$. Can you somehow prove that value of $k$ equals $1$. We may have to use eigen values or Cayley Hamilton theorem.